# regex.match isn't finding the substring?

Tags: python

I have some python code where I'm trying to parse out a specific section of a string so that I can grab a list of usernames.  I *think* I have the regex down (I tested it online and it appears to work) but when I run my test code, it doesn't seem to actually grab what I need, as I get an error:

> if parsed_mod_string.group(1):
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
>   no attribute 'group'

Which I'm understanding as basically, my code isn't returning anything with my regex comparison.  My code is below, could someone help me identify where I went wrong?

```
import re
MOD_LIST_MSG = re.compile(r":\w+\.\w+\.\w+ NOTICE #\w+ :The moderators of this room are:(.*)")

test_msg = ":tmi.twitch.tv CAP * ACK :twitch.tv/commands\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv NOTICE #secondubly :The moderators of this room are: mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4\r\n"

parsed_mod_string = MOD_LIST_MSG.match(test_msg)
if parsed_mod_string.group(1):
    mod_list = parsed_mod_string.group(1).split(', ')
    print(mod_list)
```

Comment: You would be well served to post example input and desired captured text. Also, you would do `if parsed_mod_string:` to test the match. You will get an error with `if parsed_mod_string.group(1):` if there is no match.

Comment: @user2864740 I did exactly that before trying it in python - and it works fine there, but not in my code (see: [this editor](https://vgy.me/BSiA0d.png)) which is what confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters *at the beginning of string* match the regular expression..

That is, `re.match` is an "anchored" search function.

Compare this to [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

> Scan through string looking *for the first location* where [the pattern matches..]

Comment: I honestly can't believe it was that simple (I spent hours hunting through documentation and examples to make sure I had it right).  That solved my problem!

Comment: @TaiM. Yay! FWIW - I might split the lines first (on \r\n) and then apply re.match on each line - breaking up a regular expression (or the input to such) can often times simplify a problem. Also, a literal dot is better matched with [.] or \. to avoid over-matching with the .-wildcard.